# Basic dynamical style

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem to style a simple div with react.

```
var Wireframe = React.createClass({

  render() {


    var styles = {
      height: 100,
      width: 150,
      color: 'red'
    };

    console.log('style', styles);
    return (
      <div style="{styles}"></div>
    );
  }


});
```

I don't understand why. I tried to use React.StyleSheet.create with no success.

Comment: Ok if you are searching like me, remove the -> " <- and it will be fix. {styles} instead of "{styles}"

Answer (score 1):

To use a JavaScript expression as an attribute value, [you should wrap](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#attribute-expressions) the expression in a pair of curly braces (`{}`) instead of quotes (`""`)

So basic syntax is following:

```
<Component propName={propValue} />
```

Shorthands are:

1- for passing strings:

```
<Component propName="some-string" />
```

2- for passing `true`:

```
<Component propName />
```

So, your code attemps to pass string "{styles}" as prop where object is expected. Instead you should

```
<div style={styles}></div>
```

or just inline

```
<div style={{width: "10px"}}></div>
```

Comment: great explanation i was blocked with the same bug this morning ^.^